# User input values in the global variables

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I declared two variables in the main class of Java which I made public. Please see the code below.

```
java.util.Scanner;

public class NestedExample {

    public int a,b,c;

    public static void main (String args[])
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter the first value");

        Scanner d = new Scanner(System.in);
        int a = d.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Please enter the second value");

        Scanner e = new Scanner(System.in);
        int b = e.nextInt();    

    }    
}
```

Could you please tell me if the code is correct as, it is showing an error in the Scanner command.

Regards,
Saurabh

Comment: https://www.google.de/search?q=java+Scanner+example

Comment: you missed the import keyword

Comment: The code is correct, but it is assigning the values to local variables, if that is not what you want, access static variables from static context or create an object for the class in main method

Answer (score 0):

You didn't add the `import` keyword. Change `java.util.Scanner;` to `import java.util.Scanner;`

Answer (score 0):

Import key word is missing in your code.

`import` is a Java keyword.

It declares a Java class to use in the code below the import statement. Once a Java class is declared, then the class name can be used in the code without specifying the package the class belongs to.

in order to use Scanner class you need to import it

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```